# Create link in document library SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, csom

I'm trying to create a link in a document library pointing to another document library.

Like this :

[image]

But I want to do it by code in C# for SharePoint Online. I've followed numerous guides but can't get it to work.

```
Web web = ctx2.Web;
var externalList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("LegalExternal");
ctx2.Load(externalList);
ctx2.ExecuteQuery();

string fileLink = @"https://*****.sharepoint.com/customer/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?";
                string aspxFile = GetLinkString();

                aspxFile = aspxFile.Replace("{0}", fileLink);
                FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                fileInfo.Content = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(aspxFile);
                fileInfo.Url = "Test.aspx"; //also tried Test.aspx.url

                File file = externalList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);

                ctx2.Load(externalList);
                ctx2.Load(file);
                ctx2.ExecuteQuery();

                ListItem item = file.ListItemAllFields;

                item["ContentType"] = "Link to a Document";
                FieldUrlValue itemUrl = new FieldUrlValue();
                itemUrl.Url = fileLink;
                item.FieldValues["URL"] = itemUrl;

                item.Update();

 public string GetLinkString()
        {
            string prop = "<%@ Assembly Name = 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' %>" +
                            "<%@ Register TagPrefix = 'SharePoint' Namespace='Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls' Assembly='Microsoft.SharePoint' %>" +
                            "<%@ Import Namespace = 'System.IO' %>" +
                            "<%@ Import Namespace = 'Microsoft.SharePoint' %>" +
                            "<%@ Import Namespace = 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities' %>" +
                            "<%@ Import Namespace = 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls' %>" +
                            "<html xmlns:mso='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:msdt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'>" +
                            "<Head><META Name='progid' Content='SharePoint.Link'>" +
                            "<xml>" +
                            "<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>" +
                            "<mso:URL msdt:dt='string'>{0}, {0}</mso:URL>" +
                            "<mso:ContentType msdt:dt='string'>Link to a Document</mso:ContentType>" +
                            "</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>" +
                            "</xml>" +
                            "</head>" +
                            "<body>" +
                            "<form id='Form1' runat='server'>" +
                            "<SharePoint:UrlRedirector id='Redirector1' runat='server'/>" +
                            "</form>" +
                            "</body>" +
                            "</html>";

           return prop;

}
```

I get no errors but can't get it to work

Comment: Try to remove first row in the prop: <%@ Assembly Name = 'Microsoft.SharePoint. Version 12 on SPO? I dont think so.

Comment: Look at this link http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/07/sharepoint-document-library-add.html he'S getting the Assembly dynamically.